# Custom field - Drop down. How to create?

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

Hi guys and thank you in advance.

I am extending the options available under "events". I need to create a new custome field (called 'collaboration type') that presents the user with a dropdown list (a. supported, b. hosting, c.joint, d. sponsored)... but I am not sure how to do so.

Kind regards
A.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom fields under Administer --> Customize Data and Screens --> Custom Fields. You first create a custom group for the event. You could even limit this group to a certain type of event. 
You then add a field in this group with type Text and HTML type Select.

Comment: All done, thnk you